# Displaying image at gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, web-services, gridview

I'm have 2 websites and i am trying to retrieve image in a gridview from database through web service. I use fileupload to put in image into my database at one website and retrieve at another website. My insertion of image works but My image does not appear at the gridview which i retrieve to. what's wrong with my codes?

This is how i insert my image into the database:

```
        protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FeedbackDesc = tb_description.Text;
        int FeedbackRating = Rating1.CurrentRating;
        string Image = FileUpload1.FileName;
        string fileName = "";
        int EventID = int.Parse(lbl_eventid.Text);
        //int.Parse(lbl_eventid.Text);

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/image/" + FileUpload1.FileName));

            DAL_Feedback feedback = new DAL_Feedback();
            int result = 0;
            result = feedback.Insert(FeedbackDesc, FeedbackRating, fileName, EventID);
        }
    }
```

This is my retrieve codes:

```
        public DataSet GetFeedback()
        {
        StringBuilder sql;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet Feedback;
        SqlConnection conn = dbConn.GetConnection();
        Feedback = new DataSet();
        sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.AppendLine("SELECT FeedbackID, FeedbackDesc, FeedbackRating, Image, EventID from Feedback");

        try
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql.ToString(), conn);
            da.Fill(Feedback);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errMsg = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return Feedback;
    }
}
```

This is my gridview:

```
         <asp:GridView ID="gvFeedback" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="auto-style3" Height="358px" Width="1259px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FeedbackID" HeaderText="Feedback ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FeedbackDesc" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FeedbackRating" HeaderText="Rating" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventID" HeaderText="Event ID" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="image" DataImageUrlFormatString="~/image/{0}" HeaderText="Image">
        </asp:ImageField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What type is the image stored as in the DB? I'm guessing you have to stream it back.

Comment: Why are you also saving the image to the /image folder if you only need to save it to the DB?

Comment: @IrishChieftain He's saving the image file to the "image" folder, and saving only the filename to the database. The image file itself is not stored in the db. This is common practice for storing images to reduce load on the db. He's then trying to load the image using the filename with a url in a gridview on a different website.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If OP confirms this, maybe he/she can edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does any error occur? check out your developer tool in chrome.
With error message, it would be more efficiently to debug

Comment: How does one debug server-side code with browser tools?

Comment: Maybe debug with VS. Anyway just try to find out the error message.

Comment: Just looking at the code, I think the problem is he is trying to bring back an image with a simple SELECT statement. This won't work - he needs to read it back as a stream, probably by using a HttpHandler.

Answer (score -1):

Where you have `DataImageUrlFormatString="~/image/{0}"`
the `~` refers to the current domain. You probably need to change `~` to the domain of the first website